# PHPStorm deletes line if Backspace is pressed on the default indentation level

Tags: ide, phpstorm, code-formatting

After upgrading from 7.x to 8.x I noticed an annoying new "feature". When on an empty line (after pressing enter), then pressing backspace (which used to get rid of the indentation character right in front of the caret) the line is erased and the caret jumps back to the end of the line above.

Given the following code snippet and caret placement:

> [image]

pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> does this:

> [image]

How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of PhpStorm 9+, this setting is located in it's own section under `Editor > General > Smart Keys > Backspace`. Setting the `Unindent` drop-down to `Disabled` will give you the behaviour you would expect.

[image: Editor > General > Smart Keys > Backspace > Unindent]

---

The solution is to disable "Backspace smart indent" by going to `File > Settings` (or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) then

1. navigating to `IDE Settings > Editor > Smart Keys`
2. searching for `Backspace smart indent`

and removing the tick from check box next to said option.

[image: IDE Settings > Editor > Smart Keys > Backspace smart indent]